# What's the mdadm --incremental function?

Tags: mdadm

I can understand this command:

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb2
```

but I don't know what the purpose to do this:

```
mdadm --incremental /dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The incremental mode](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mdadm.8.html#INCREMENTAL_MODE) is used to assemble the array, mostly when starting the system or when plugging the RAID drives. It's basically a way of telling MD "I found this drive with MD metadata on it, try to make an array from it". Once you added all drives needed to start the array, it will be automatically started (e.g. after last RAID drive is found during boot or connected).

Simple example with RAID0 with 2 disks:

```
$ sudo mdadm --incremental /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sdb attached to /dev/md/127, not enough to start (1).
$ sudo mdadm --incremental /dev/sdc
mdadm: /dev/sdc attached to /dev/md/127, which has been started.
```

If you use `--incremental` together with `--fail` it will remove the device from the array (even if the device is not available at all, e.g. the `/dev/sdX` doesn't exist you can still remove it from the array). This is used to replace faulty or missing drives.